# Citing a book with diacritics in its title using LuaLaTeX and Biber

Tags: biblatex, luatex, biber

I am using LuaLaTeX and Biber. The document class is scrbook and I use the package fontspec. However, I am unable to cite this book: https://publications.efeo.fr/en/livres/908_a-critical-edition-and-an-annotated-translation-of-the-akan-u-part-1-ka-i-iy-ainirai. The current biblatex entry is:

```
@book{wilden2018critical,
    author = {Eva Wilden},
    title = {{A Critical Edition and an Annotated Translation of the Akanāṉūṟu (Part 1 - Kaḷiṟṟiyāainirai)}},
    year = {2018},
    publisher = {{\'E}cole Fran{\c{c}}aise d'Extr{\^e}me-Orient}
}
```

The problem is, that some characters are missing in the compiled PDF, such as ṟ or ṉ. Is there a way to solve this? I tried `\b{n}` for ṉ, which does not work, as ṉ does not appear in the compiled PDF either. Or `{\,\textsubscript{\_}\!\!\!n}`, which does look ugly.

Comment: Seems to be working fine, it's just that your font is missing the required glyphs, i.e. it doesn't know how to display `ṉ` etc. You'll probably have to use a font that supports it, if this is important to you. If that is not an option, certain missing glyphs can be imported from another font, but simply switching would be the simplest option.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default font Latin Modern doesn't have the diacritics you want, so the solution would be to use a font which has them. The following seems to work.

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex
% arara: lualatex
% arara: clean: { extensions: [aux,log,blg,out,bbl,bcf,run.xml] }
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\diacritics}{cmunci.otf}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{ref.bib}
@book{wilden2018critical,
    author = {Eva Wilden},
    title = {{\diacritics A Critical Edition and an Annotated Translation of the Akanāṉūṟu (Part 1 - Kaḷiṟṟiyāainirai)}},
    year = {2018},
    publisher = {{\'E}cole Fran{\c{c}}aise d'Extr{\^e}me-Orient}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{wilden2018critical}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

---

Note: `cmunci.otf` is the name for computer modern italic font. Using `\newfontfamily{\diacritics}{CMU-Serif-Italic}` also works with LuaLaTeX, but fails with XeLaTeX, hence it is advisable to use the real name of the font to maintain the cross-engine-compatibility.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

The test file:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{wilden2018critical,
    author = {Eva Wilden},
    title = {A Critical Edition and an Annotated Translation of the 
             Akanāṉūṟu (Part 1 - Kaḷiṟṟiyāainirai)},
    year = {2018},
    publisher = {École Française d'Extrême-Orient}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{wilden2018critical}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Upon running with XeLaTeX, Biber and XeLaTeX again, we get

```
Missing character: There is no ṉ (U+1E49) in font [lmroman10-italic]:mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ṟ (U+1E5F) in font [lmroman10-italic]:mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ṟ (U+1E5F) in font [lmroman10-italic]:mapping=tex-text;!
Missing character: There is no ṟ (U+1E5F) in font [lmroman10-italic]:mapping=tex-text;!
```

OK, the font hasn't the required glyphs, but we can emulate them with composite ones.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{wilden2018critical,
    author = {Eva Wilden},
    title = {A Critical Edition and an Annotated Translation of the 
             Akanāṉūṟu (Part 1 - Kaḷiṟṟiyāainirai)},
    year = {2018},
    publisher = {École Française d'Extrême-Orient}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newunicodechar{ṉ}{n^^^^0331}
\newunicodechar{ṟ}{r^^^^0331}

\begin{document}

\cite{wilden2018critical}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

I found the decomposition with a helper application that shows Unicode points.

[image]

Your operating system should have something similar to UnicodeChecker on macOS.

Comment: Actually, there's a whole Unicode block dedicated to COMBINING DIACRITICAL MARKS (U+0300 – U+036F) … Should you ever have a need for Accents Grave, Acute, Circumflex; Diaereses; Dots, Tildes and Macrons above and below (and oh so much more), look no further: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/block/U+0300